# Easy expanation of setting up Openssl on Windows

Tags: php, openssl, gdata-api, google-calendar-api

I really want to get the google Calendar Api up an running.  I found a [great article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-googleclndr/) about how to get started. I downloaded the Zend GData classes.  I have php 5 running on my dev box and all the exetensions should be loading.

I cant get openssl running and recieve the following error when I try to run any of the example page which should connect to my Google Calendar.

```
Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Unable to Connect to ssl://www.google.com:443. Error #24063472: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?'
```

I have looked in many places to try to get OpenSSL running on my machine and installed.

Does anyone know of a simple failsafe tutorial to get this combination up and running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this use of SSL is part of the Zend GData library so I assume it is correct. I think not having OpenSSL correctly installed is my main issue.

Answer (score 2):

First it would be helpful if you mentioned your OS, I'll assume windows.

Check the output of

```
<?php echo phpinfo();?>
```

If the OpenSSL library is enabled  "Registered Stream Socket Transports" will mention ssl

Your php.ini should have

```
[PHP_OPENSSL]
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

If its not there, or you add it and php complains then you should re-run the installer and go through the list of extensions, it would be under OpenSSL.

Answer (score 0):

Could you have mistyped the PROTOCOL in the URL?  It should be HTTPS, not "SSL".  For example, , not SSL://www.google.com:443.  Can you double check this in your example client and make sure it is HTTPS, not SSL.